# Flux state.update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm new to the Flux library, and have been working through the [tutorial](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc/) on my project. I'm getting a little bit lost around the bit where we edit todos. In particular, I'm confused by this block of code:

```
case TodoActionTypes.TOGGLE_TODO:
    return state.update(
      action.id,
      todo => todo.set('complete', !todo.complete),
    );
```

I've been searching for the ".update" method in flux on google, but every search just redirects me to a beginner's guide to flux, which doesn't reference any .update method.

Right now, my state should contain something that looks like this:

```
state = {id1: 
        {
         foo: 'bar', 
         fizz:'buzz'},
         }
```

My goal is to create an editable attribute, where a user can update the value stored in foo to whatever they please. Presently, I'm not seeing a clear path forward using the state.update method that flux utilizes. I would like to know how state.update works in flux, and how I might use it to edit the value stored in foo for a given id.

Edit: Further exploration of the documents in the react flux tutorial lead me to this block of code:

```
      case TodoActionTypes.EDIT_TODO:
    return state.setIn([action.id, 'text'], action.text);
```

While I'm still unclear on how the set.update and state.setIn methods work, I at least found the means to continue on my project. That being said, I strongly dislike copying and pasting my code without at least understanding how the methods are supposed to work, what arguments they require, etc. I'd still like to know more about these methods.

Edit 2: It's been pointed out to me that this comes from Immutable.js, not Flux. [The docs for Immutable](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/update) provide further clarification.

Comment: You mean [this one](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/update)?

Comment: That appears to be the source of update(). I never considered that it might be coming from the Immutable library-- thanks very much!

Comment: Nice. FYI, the more popular alternative to Flux nowadays is the (arguably simpler) Redux library, and an alternative to ImmutableJS is `immutability-helper`. Explore your options before settling on one framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function came from the Immutable.js library, not from React as I'd believed previously.